# Paypal SDK - paymentId vs invoice_number vs orderId

Tags: paypal

I find it a little hard to understand what is the difference between the paymentId invoice_number and orderId.

This is a demo code in nodejs where I mark the fields.
Also is there a way to get the invoice_number of the item that the user want to pay for before the execuation of the payment.

```js
const express = require('express')
const  bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());

paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox', 
    'client_id': 
    'client_secret':
});

//Is being called from client
app.post('/pay', (req, res, next) => {
    createOrder(req.body.transactionId, paymentUrl => {
        res.send({paymentUrl});
    });
})


//Is called from paypal after user confirmed the payment
app.get('/process', (req, res, next) => {
    //Can I get here the invoice_number in order to understand what the payment for before charging ?

    var paymentId = req.query.paymentId;
    var payerId = {
        'payer_id': req.query.PayerID
    };
    var order;

    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, payerId, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
            if (payment.state === 'approved' &&
                payment.transactions &&
                payment.transactions[0].related_resources &&
                payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].order) {
             
           
                orderId = payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].order.id;
                //What is the difference between the invoice_number payment.id and orderId
                res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/order/payment/success/' + orderId);
            } else {
                res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/order/payment/failure/' + orderId);
            }
        }
    });
});
//Should be called only from paypal
app.post('/error', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Error from paypal");
})

app.listen(3300, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})

function createOrder(data, callback) {
    let invoice_number = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);

    var payReq = JSON.stringify({
        intent: 'order',
        payer: {
            payment_method: 'paypal'
        },
        redirect_urls: {
            return_url: 'http://localhost:3300/process',
            cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/order/payment/failure'
        },
        transactions: [{
            amount: {
                total: '30.03',
                currency: 'USD'
            },
            description: 'This is the payment transaction description.',
            invoice_number: invoice_number, //should be the transactionId
            payment_options: {
                allowed_payment_method: 'INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE'
            }
        }]
    });

    paypal.payment.create(payReq, function (error, payment) {
        var links = {};

        if (error) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
        } else {
            // Capture HATEOAS links
            payment.links.forEach(function (linkObj) {
                links[linkObj.rel] = {
                    href: linkObj.href,
                    method: linkObj.method
                };
            })

            if (links.hasOwnProperty('approval_url')) {
                callback(links.approval_url.href);
            } else {
                console.error('no redirect URI present');
            }
        }
    });
}
```